# How can I smooth out uneven scroll behavior using a trackpad in Macvim?

Tags: performance, trackpad, macos, macvim

I have just installed MacVim on my new Macbook.

But I have a problem: on Linux I was able to scroll through my code—vertically moving my cursor—by using my trackpad. But on Macvim this doesn't work for me.

When scrolling in Macvim, the buffer/window scrolls but the cursor doesn't move.

I made a little video demonstrating the issue:
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeBIfwhRL5Q&feature=youtu.be) you see the buffer moving when I scroll using my trackpad, but not my cursor scrolling.

I tried to fix this error by using the command `:set mouse=a`, but without success. I also took a look at MouseTerm (using SIBML), but this doesn't seem trustworthy and a little bit overkill to just enable good scrolling behavior.

I found a solution which came close:

```
nnoremap <ScrollWheelUp> k
nnoremap <ScrollWheelDown> j
```

However, this scrolling is not even close to smooth and I was hoping for a more elegant way to solve this than remapping.

By the way, scrolling does work fine in the normal Vim using the Terminal as long as Mouse Reporting is enabled.

TL;DR: How to enable smooth scrolling behavior with trackpad in Macvim?
Thanks!